# VC++ How to SUM two biginteger numbers

Tags: visual-c++, sum, c++-cli, biginteger

Say I have

```
static System::Numerics::BigInteger MinimoNumero; int16_t Uno = 1;
static System::Numerics::BigInteger MaximoNumero;
static const std::string            MaximoNumeroString = "91389681247993671255432112333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333";
  
MaximoNumero = System::Numerics::BigInteger::Parse(marshal_as<String^>(MaximoNumeroString));
MinimoNumero = System::Numerics::BigInteger::Parse("1");
```

How can I SUM 1 to MaximoNumero so I want a result as BigInteger as 91389681247993671255432112333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334

If I use

```
System::Numerics::BigInteger NUM = MinimoNumero + MaximoNumero;
```

then I got error "more than one operator "+" matches these operands.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (generally) use the plain arithmetic operators on the `BigInteger` type. Instead, call the relevant member function(s) of the `BigInteger` type – in this case, the `Add` function:

```
System::Numerics::BigInteger NUM = System::Numerics::BigInteger::Add(MinimoNumero, MaximoNumero);
```

Comment: I discovered and used: System::Numerics::BigInteger result = System::Numerics::BigInteger::operator+(MinimoNumero, MaximoNumero); which seems, is about the same as System::Numerics::BigInteger::Add. But I mark your reply as Answer. However I could not understand why I need to call a function in order to SUM just two bigintegers, I meant, I cannot understand Why I cannot use operand "+", when in the same scenario I can use a multiplier operand "*"

Comment: I could *maybe* offer some clarification but I had issues compiling your code ... like my version of Visual Studio doesn't allow the `static` on the `BigInteger` declarations. And it can't use your version of `marshal_as`. Probably different versions or dialects?

Comment: Possibly a fuller code sample would be helpful. That would certainly improve your question.